# Show there isn't the same probability for events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

I'm currently reading about statistics and I'm trying to figure out all the different distributions, tests, hypotheses etc.

I have come across an exercise which is basically like this:

I'm given four numbers including x1, x2, x3 and n, where n is the total number of trials. The numbers for x1, x2 and x3 are all different.

Then I'm given a model M0 which states that (X1, X2, X3) is distributed as the multinomial distribution with parameters n and (π1, π2, π3) where (π1, π2, π3) belongs to ∏^(3).

My task is show that there is not equal probability for the three events.

So, my first thought was to set up a hypothesis H0 which should state something like (π1, π2, π3) = (p1, p2, p3), p1 ≠ p2 ≠ p3, p1 + p2 + p3 = 1.

I don't know if this would be the correct way to set up the hypothesis?

Also, I'm confused about what test should be used to show that the probability isn't equal for the three events. Clearly, it isn't a t-test or an F-test, since these are for mean and standard deviation/variance. Could it be a multinomial test?

Help would really be appreciated.

Nobody that can help?

Comment: Consider the [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).

Comment: But what about my hypothesis? Is it correct? I think I have to state something like H0: [There is not the same probability for x1, x2 and x3]

Comment: No, I'd say that the null hypothesis would be that they *do* have the same probability; i.e., that $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = 1/3$.  Then you would show that that hypothesis is sustained/not sustained at the $p = 0.01$ (or $0.05$, if you feel permissive) level.  Generally, the null hypothesis is the option that embodies the principle of indifference, that any variation is just due to random chance.

Comment: One reason for that is that you must have a hypothesis to confirm or disprove, and if it isn't the uniform one, what would you choose?  Anything you chose, other than the uniform one, would have "mirror images" that are at least as justifiable as the one you chose.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Regarding the null hypothesis, you're right. The null hypothesis is usually the one stating that "they are the same". So the following should be correct? H0: (π1, π2, π3) = (p1, p2, p3), p1 = p2 = p3 = 1/3. And then the next step would be to do a chi-squared-test? So I have to set up some expected values at first?

Comment: I'd look at how the test is run.  You're essentially comparing the sample values against the expected distribution, given the uniform parameters specified by $H_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up getting a p-value which was smaller than the statistical significance which means the null hypothesis should be rejected. However, I have one question. After I calculated the chi-squared value (or is it called test statistic?) I had to use Excel to calculate the p-value. What is the normal way to calculate the p-value, when you have the chi-squared value and the degrees of freedom?